# Flash color of table elements

Tags: jquery, html, css, datatables

I have a large table with cells that have various words in them. I want to find all of the cells with "Failed" as their text, start all of them flashing between red and transparent, then stop the flashing of any cell that is clicked on (but keep the others going until clicked one by one).

I've found a way to find each cell with "Failed" and assign a class to it:

```
function updateTableColors() {
    // first 3 rows are headers
    var numCols = document.getElementById("vimTable").rows[4].cells.length;

    for(var i = 1; i < numCols; i++) {
        $( '#vimTable td:nth-child(' + i + ')' ).each(function() {
            var cellText = $(this).text();

            if(cellText === "Failed") {
                $(this).removeClass();
                $(this).addClass("failed");
            }
            else if( cellText === "") { 
                             // cell doesn't contain text (could be image)
                // nothing for now
            }
            else {
                $(this).removeClass();
            }                   
        });
    }

    return false;
}

// Re-run formatting on click
document.onclick = function() {
    updateTableColors();
}
```

My plan of attack was to check each of the elements with the "failed" class, then toggle whether it has a "failed_red" or "failed_transparent" class and give it a color based on that, but I haven't been successful doing this without going through each element by unique id. Thanks for your help!

Note: I'm also using the jquery dataTables plug-in (datatables.net), and my solution can't use HTML5.

EDIT: the jQuery toggleClass() method is very helpful here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access all elements with a certain class combo using jquery:

```
$('.failed.failed_red').css('background-color', 'red');
```

and

```
$('.failed.failed_transparent').css('background-color', 'none');
```

Comment: Thanks @StaticVoid. I just got started so I can't upvote you, but I'll come back and upvote it once I have more reputation.